# Django - One query to get M2M objects

Tags: django, many-to-many, prefetch

`Entry` model and `Reference` have M2M relationship.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  references = models.ManyToManyField(Reference, blank=True)

class Reference(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
```

I need to iterate over the entries and get a field from `Entry`. Also for each `entry`, I need to iterate over its `references`, and get data from each `reference`.

`prefetch_related` is not caching all the reference data. For each `entry`, I am hitting the db again when I call `entry.references.all()`, and the performance is terrible (I have 100k entries, and 500k references).

How can I get all the data in one database call?

```
qs = Entry.objects.prefetch_related('references').all()
for entry in qs:
   # do something with entry
   for ref in entry.references.all():
     # do something with ref
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed that `Reference` has a foreign key to `Source`. When I include `Source` model in  `prefetch_related`, performance went from 8 minutes to 80 seconds (which is acceptable).

`qs = CVEEntry.objects.prefetch_related('references', 'references__source').all()`